# Visual Composer on wordpress 4.5 invisible parts

Tags: css, wordpress, visual-composer

I made a site with wordpress using visual composer.

When I am logged in, I can see everything good but when I log out from admin zone or when i visit the home page of the site, all the animated css things are invisible (but present) and also the youtube video background on a row is gone.

How can i fix it?

Wordpress 4.5 and Visual Composer 4.12

you can see the situation at http://socialvip-app.com

Comment: You haven't provided anywhere near enough information with which to see the issue you're having, never mind trying to assist you. Please review http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

i thing its your Visual Composer problem so login your wp-admin go to plugin find visual composer Deactivate and after some time active it i hope it's work on that time .

Comment: i have get this error and that time i just change theme and see after it's run  perfect now i hope its help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try Once by Changing your Permalinks as default.

---

OR else Deactivate and Reactivate your plugin again .